# Http Status 404: Servlet ViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a Spring-boot application to perform crud operations using hibernate.

I have mentioned the Dispatcher servlet in the web-xml by the name servlet-context in appservlet in spring in WEB-INF. 
heres my web.xml config

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and I have mentioned all the beans , view-resolver in the dispatcher-servlet

heres the servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="neonowl" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

My jsp page 'person.jsp' is in the views folder inside WEB-INF. Now when i run the application on server I'm getting Http status 404
message /projectname/
description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Please help debug this.

Comment: Can you share the `application.properties` and your controller code?

Comment: Can you add the Controller code ?

Comment: Tell us more, you mention person.jsp (what's the url you're calling). Please share your stacktrace error for /projectname

Answer (score 0):

From this [baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial), we have the followint:

> Spring MVC architecture uses ViewResolvers internally to handle views, which enable you to render models in the browser.
>
> The ViewResolver maps view names to actual views.
>
> And the Spring framework comes with quite a few view resolvers e.g. InternalResourceViewResolver, XmlViewResolver, ResourceBundleViewResolver

Regarding your issue:

You need a `ViewResolver` bean to be present in your application context and register it via:

```
@Bean
 public ViewResolver configureViewResolver() {
     InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolve = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
     viewResolve.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
     viewResolve.setSuffix(".jsp");
 
     return viewResolve;
 }
```

And respect the mode in which this `ViewResolver` maps internal resources to external URLs(well documented [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internalresourceviewresolver-configuration-example/)
[image]

Comment: Note that this can also be done in the `application.properties` file...

Comment: why do i need a configuration class i've already made the bean for view resolver in the spring-servlet

Comment: It.s just an example for helping you understand. Remember that each answer requires effort and time from the users which provided the answer, so that the.community grows